# Finding and matching reversed strings efficiently in R

Tags: r, string, loops, match, reverse

I have a large number of strings (~280,000) that all have the following format "ABC12D/XYZ34A". In my data, each of those strings has a duplicate entry that is identical but in reverse, e.g. "XYZ34A/ABC12D" for the example above. So, my data looks something like this:

```
1    "ABC12D/XYZ34A"
2    "TUR44F/SWP29R"
3    "PLL93S/WQQ22F"
4    "YNV77C/AAZ05S"
5    "SWP29R/TUR44F"
6    "AAZ05S/YNV77C"
7    "CLK86G/ERF74Q"
8    "XYZ34A/ABC12D"
9    "ERF74Q/CLK86G"
10   "WQQ22F/PLL93S"
```

Row 1 matches row 8, row 2 matches row 5, etc.

My aims are: 1) for a given string, find where its reversed entry is and keep this index and then 2) replace the reverse entry with the non-reverse entry:

```
1   "ABC12D/XYZ34A" 8
2   "TUR44F/SWP29R" 5
3   "PLL93S/WQQ22F" 10
4   "YNV77C/AAZ05S" 6
5   "TUR44F/SWP29R" 0
6   "YNV77C/AAZ05S" 0
7   "CLK86G/ERF74Q" 9
8   "ABC12D/XYZ34A" 0
9    "CLK86G/ERF74Q" 0
10   "PLL93S/WQQ22F" 0
```

Currently, I do this in the following way using a loop:

```
df <- data.frame(c("ABC12D/XYZ34A", "TUR44F/SWP29R", "PLL93S/WQQ22F", 
"YNV77C/AAZ05S", "SWP29R/TUR44F", "AAZ05S/YNV77C", "CLK86G/ERF74Q", 
"XYZ34A/ABC12D", "ERF74Q/CLK86G", "WQQ22F/PLL93S"), stringsAsFactors = 
FALSE)

colnames(df) <- "entries"
df

# Reverse function
reverse.entry <- function(string) {
  string.reversed <- paste(rev(strsplit(string, "/")[[1]]), collapse = '/')
  string.reversed
}

duplicate.flag <- list() 
duplicate.idx <- list() 

# Find and replace reversed entries
for (i in 1:dim(df)[[1]]) {
  # current entry
  string = df[i,]

  # reverse the current entry
  string.reversed <- reverse.entry(string)

  # if any other entry matches the reversed string get match index 
  if (grepl(string.reversed, df)) {

    print(sprintf("%d found a reversal", i))
    idx <- which(df == string.reversed)
    duplicate.flag[i] <- 1;
    duplicate.idx[i] <- idx;
    # replace reversed strings with original strings
    df[idx,] <- string
  } else {
    duplicate.flag[i] <- 0;
    duplicate.idx[i] <- 0;
  }

}

data.frame(df, unlist(duplicate.idx), unlist(duplicate.flag))
```

However, this is quite slow and is taking several hours. Is there a better way of programming this? I'm fairly new to R and programming so am not terribly good at vectorization etc. Since each entry has one reverse entry, I could also just have the loop for 1:dim(df)[[1]] / 2. Would that already save a lot of time?

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a rule to identify who is the original and who is the reverse? Does the original come up first in the dataframe?

Comment: No hard rule and it doesn't matter. I've been treating the one that comes first as the original but as long as at the end they match it doesn't matter which one was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
df$no <- seq_along(df$entries) #number the entries
df$rev <- gsub("(.+)/(.+)","\\2/\\1",df$entries) #calculate reverse entries
df$whererev <- match(df$rev, df$entries) #identify where reversed entries occur
df$whererev[df$whererev>df$no] <- NA #remove the first of each duplicated pair 
df$entries[!is.na(df$whererev)] <- df$rev[!is.na(df$whererev)] #replace duplicates

df
   no       entries           rev whererev
1   1 ABC12D/XYZ34A XYZ34A/ABC12D       NA
2   2 TUR44F/SWP29R SWP29R/TUR44F       NA
3   3 PLL93S/WQQ22F WQQ22F/PLL93S       NA
4   4 YNV77C/AAZ05S AAZ05S/YNV77C       NA
5   5 TUR44F/SWP29R TUR44F/SWP29R        2
6   6 YNV77C/AAZ05S YNV77C/AAZ05S        4
7   7 CLK86G/ERF74Q ERF74Q/CLK86G       NA
8   8 ABC12D/XYZ34A ABC12D/XYZ34A        1
9   9 CLK86G/ERF74Q CLK86G/ERF74Q        7
10 10 PLL93S/WQQ22F PLL93S/WQQ22F        3
```

Note that I have marked the second duplicate rather than the first, as this makes it easier (and probably substantially quicker) to replace the second one, rather than having to look it up from the first one.  (Line 4 would have `<` rather than `>` if you wanted to recreate your marking of the first of each duplicated pair).

Comment: great solution!  Is the `sapply()` step needed?  I think `df$whererev <- match(df$rev, df$entries)` gives the same result and is nearly 3x as fast.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that is better.  I'll update the solution. Many thanks!

Comment: The string does not reverse, just a swap of the two elements either side of the /.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
require(data.table)
get_index <- function(string,values,current_index){
  string_present <- match(string,values)
  string_present[string_present<current_index] <- 0
  return(string_present)
}

mydata <- c("ABC12D/XYZ34A","TUR44F/SWP29R","PLL93S/WQQ22F","YNV77C/AAZ05S","SWP29R/TUR44F","AAZ05S/YNV77C","CLK86G/ERF74Q","XYZ34A/ABC12D","ERF74Q/CLK86G","WQQ22F/PLL93S")
mydf <- data.table(mystring = mydata,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydf[,revmystring:=gsub("(.+)\\/(.+)","\\2\\/\\1",mystring)]
mydf[,duplicate_index:=get_index(revmystring,mystring,.I)]
```

The solution it gives is:

```
> mydf
         mystring   revmystring duplicate_index
 1: ABC12D/XYZ34A XYZ34A/ABC12D               8
 2: TUR44F/SWP29R SWP29R/TUR44F               5
 3: PLL93S/WQQ22F WQQ22F/PLL93S              10
 4: YNV77C/AAZ05S AAZ05S/YNV77C               6
 5: SWP29R/TUR44F TUR44F/SWP29R               0
 6: AAZ05S/YNV77C YNV77C/AAZ05S               0
 7: CLK86G/ERF74Q ERF74Q/CLK86G               9
 8: XYZ34A/ABC12D ABC12D/XYZ34A               0
 9: ERF74Q/CLK86G CLK86G/ERF74Q               0
10: WQQ22F/PLL93S PLL93S/WQQ22F               0
```

You can implement this without `data.table` as well.

Comment: This works nicely to give me the duplicate index but doesnt replace the reverse with original entry. Adding this line did it though: 
`mydf$mystring[mydf$duplicate_index] <-mydf$mystring[mydf$duplicate_index > 0 ]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a propostion using `outer` and `gsub`:

```
## Create a matrix of correspondence o between elements and reverses
o = outer(df[,1],df[,1],function(x,y) gsub("(.*)/(.*)","\\2/\\1",y)==x)
o[upper.tri(o)] = F
## Identify the indices of correspondence
df$ind = unlist(apply(o,2,function(x) which(x==T)[1]))
df$ind[is.na(df$ind)] = 0
## Replace reverses by originals
df[,1][df$ind[df$ind!=0]] = df[,1][df$ind!=0]
```

This returns:

```
        V1        ind
1  ABC12D/XYZ34A   8
2  TUR44F/SWP29R   5
3  PLL93S/WQQ22F  10
4  YNV77C/AAZ05S   6
5  TUR44F/SWP29R   0
6  YNV77C/AAZ05S   0
7  CLK86G/ERF74Q   9
8  ABC12D/XYZ34A   0
9  CLK86G/ERF74Q   0
10 PLL93S/WQQ22F   0
```